# How to getStaticProps with next static html export?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm creating static HTML pages with Nextjs which will work along with JAVA backend API.

I use `next build & next export` to export static pages.

Here is example of my page code:

```
export default function App({ somedata }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Head>
                <title>test</title>
            </Head>
            <Main countries={somedata} />
        </div>
    );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/somedata'); <!--- this can't be called during building
    const data = await res.json()

    return {
        props: {
            data,
        },
    };
}
```

When I run `next build & next export` I get:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/promo/somepagename". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error
FetchError: request to http://localhost:3000/api/somedata failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
```

How this can be solved?

Comment: Is `http://localhost:3000/api/somedata` pointing to your Java API, or is that an API route from Next.js?

Comment: @juliomalves it point on my Java API, but it works only on prod, from localhost I don't have access to this API. So I want Next.js to request this api when page loaded, not when I build it

Comment: If you want the request to happen when the page loads and still export static pages you need to move the request to the client.